# Monotouch spotify binding

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind the spotify api to monotouch. But can't seem to get it working, and i think i'm a little in over my head ;).

What i tried:

- I extracted the libspotify.a from the ios libspotify.framework.
- I added the libspotify.a to my project.

I followed the explanations mentioned here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linking_native_libraries to create the binding and added the extra gcc_flags to the project.

Now it all compiles and linkes but when i run it i get the exception: system.dllnotfoundexception: __internal

I have no idea of what i'm doing wrong here. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Richard.

Comment: Did you have any luck binding this?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `__Internal`, not `__internal`.